# Typescript auto generated JS file: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier"

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

Currently working on a Blazor project where I want advanced mapping functionality, using the Leaflet.js library with typescript bindings.

I have added leaflet and @types/leaflet as node modules for allowing typescript support.

With everything ready and running, the browser console shows the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "leaflet". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

There is one line generated at the top of the JS file:

```js
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

If I remove this line, everything works, but I can't remove it manually because it's generated automatically from my TS file, where it's needed.

I suspect my mistake is in tsconfig, or in the typescript file itself.

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": "typescript",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/scripts",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
}
```

Typescript file:

```js
import * as L from 'leaflet'

let map: L.Map;
let apiKey: string = "";
let mapStyle: string = 'saitken88/cl2vcjae400aw14qoiawg02c8'
let centreLatLong: L.LatLngExpression = [51.509865, -0.118092];

let mapOptions: L.MapOptions = {
    minZoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 9,
    center: centreLatLong,
    zoom: 6,
    attributionControl: false,
};

function initMap(mapId: string) {
    console.log('init map');
    map = L.map(mapId, mapOptions).setView(centreLatLong, 13);

    L.tileLayer(`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}`, {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: mapStyle,
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: apiKey,
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Compiled JS file:

```js
import * as L from 'leaflet';
let map;
let apiKey = "";
let mapStyle = 'saitken88/cl2vcjae400aw14qoiawg02c8';
let centreLatLong = [51.509865, -0.118092];
let mapOptions = {
    minZoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 9,
    center: centreLatLong,
    zoom: 6,
    attributionControl: false,
};
function initMap(mapId) {
    console.log('init map');
    map = L.map(mapId, mapOptions).setView(centreLatLong, 13);
    L.tileLayer(`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}`, {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: mapStyle,
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: apiKey,
    }).addTo(map);
}
//# sourceMappingURL=property-map.js.map
```

index.html scripts:

```html
    <script src="scripts/maps/leaflet.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="scripts/maps/property-map.js" type="module"></script>
```

Not sure if this is needed but this is my packake.json

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

I understand webpack might be a solution here, and have tried it, but frankly it seemed overly cumbersome for just getting one typescript file to compile nicely.

Comment: Is this a node module or local file? This Error normaly only occurres when you want to import a local js file

Comment: I guess you're missing `"module": "es2020",` or `"module": "es6",` in `compilerOptions`. See [Specify what module code is generated.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#module).

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky it's a local JS file which is generated automatically from a local typescript file.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Try to add `./` to as prefix, because local files need to accessed via relative path

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky I cannot do that. It's a library imported in a Typescript file. It's declared as `import L from "leaflet"` and so that's how it compiles into Javascript. I don't want to alter the JS file because it's auto generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler (`tsc`), just by itself, does not perform any bundling (on the contrary of webpack typically). It compiles each `*.ts` file individually, and outputs corresponding `*.js` files representing each of them, *without touching the import paths*.

Hence your `import * as L from 'leaflet';` line is copied as-is into the generated JS file.

When you load that generated JS file with `<script src="scripts/maps/property-map.js" type="module"></script>`, the browser understands the import syntax (thanks to the module type), but there [the module specifier needs to be different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_features_into_your_script) from your TypeScript project:

> Note: In some module systems, you can omit the file extension and the leading `/`, `./`, or `../` (e.g. `'modules/square'`). This doesn't work in native JavaScript modules.

Hence your error message.

You can try these 2 possible solutions:

1. Get rid of the import
2. Use ES module absolute import path as an URL

## 1. Get rid of the import

Assuming your `scripts/maps/leaflet.js` file is the actual Leaflet library script in [UMD form](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet-src.js) (so that it provides the global `L` object) (either the source or minified version), then you actually do not need to import it explicitly:

- In your TypeScript project, you can remove the import line; TS will still know what `L` is, because [it eagerly loads definitions from your `node_modules/@types` folder](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots):

> By default all *visible* ”`@types`” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered *visible*.

- In the browser loading the generated JS file without the import, it knows what `L` is, because it is previously assigned by Leaflet library as UMD

## 2. Use ES module absolute import path as an URL

If you prefer sticking to explicit `import`, then you could still load Leaflet with an absolute path, but to be compatible with the browser native JS modules, absolute paths are actually URL's:

```js
import * as L from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js";
```

Again, the TS compiler will copy that path untouched, and the browser will now be happy (and you can even get rid of the `<script src="scripts/maps/leaflet.js" type="module"></script>` tag in your `index.html` file; the latter will *automatically* load Leaflet from the specified URL, as intended from JS modules!)

However, your TS project, on the contrary, will no longer understand that path, and therefore no longer know what `L` is.

To make it happy again, we can tell TypeScript what that import path is in terms of types, using the [`paths` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) in `tsconfig.json`:

> A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the `baseUrl`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".", // Required for paths
    "paths": {
      "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js": [
        "node_modules/@types/leaflet/index" // Re-map to the type
      ]
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

With this, we get the "best of both worlds": type safety, and native browser ES modules (hence no need for a bundler like webpack)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I went for "Option 1: Get rid of the import". After doing that, I got an error telling me "L refers to a UMD global but the current file is a module". This is because I had changed whole file file to the form "export class PropertyMap....". I solved the final error by removing the export part. It works and I am pleased. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the [`allowUmdGlobalAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowUmdGlobalAccess) option?

Comment: You sir are the gift that keeps on giving. Many thanks!